# Why won't this CSS class work?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have a simple code in Mangento and trying to change padding for li class current:

```
<div class="pages">
<strong>Page:</strong>
<ol>
<li class="current">1</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

I have tried these two but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
li .current{margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
.current li {margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the Magento platform, it's a CSS only question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

CSS is trying to find child element with `current` class in your first `li .current` CSS and same in secound it is try to find child `li` :

```
li .current{margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
.current li {margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
```

So if you want to apply CSS on your `li` with `current` class, it should be like this:

`li.current{margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}`

Answer (score 2):

```
li .current{margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
```

In above line you have space between "li" and ".current".
So you should have:

```
li.current{margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-top:5px;}
```

Comment: typo in the correct css. Should be li.current